# React trying to delete a item from a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and I'm trying to delete an item from the list. I tried a couple of solutions but couldn't find anything to make it work. I would need an extra eye to see what I'm missing...

My code to call the delete function

```
handleDeletePrice = deletePrice => {

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    // spreads out the previous list and delete the price with a unique id(date)
    priceArr: prevState.priceArr.filter(item => item.date !== deletePrice)
  }));
};
```

and here's where I called the function in the hook(?) component. This displays a list of the prices with a delete button in each price box.

```
{this.state.priceArr.map((props) => (
              <PriceBox
                {...props}
                key={props.date}
                toggleEditing={this.toggleItemEditing}
                handleDeletePrice={this.handleDeletePrice}
                onChange={this.handleItemUpdate}
              />
            ))}
```

And in the Single Price Box Component, here's where I added the click to delete the price:

```
{this.props.handleDeletePrice && (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="delete-btn"
                    onClick={() => this.props.handleDeletePrice()}
                    >
                      X
                    </button>
                    )}
```

To see my full code, you can check out my demo at CodeSandBox in which I loaded my github repo in to display my code. https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kikidesignnet/caissa

In this demo, you click on the `Prices` button and a Popup window open. It's another page in this single page application. In this window, you can see the list of the prices and an `X` button in each price box. I am also trying to use the `date` as a unique id since each price is supposed to be entered once a day. In other words, I'm trying to use the `date` as a unique id to delete the price box.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are not passing an argument when you call your `handleDeletePrice` function in your PriceBox component.

Comment: That's what I thought. How do I pass an argument? I did console.log the `deletePrice` and it returned undefined....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand business domain, but I think this approach can help

```js
{this.state.priceArr.map((props) => (
              <PriceBox
                {...props}
                key={props.date}
                price={props.price}
                toggleEditing={this.toggleItemEditing}
                handleDeletePrice={this.handleDeletePrice}
                onChange={this.handleItemUpdate}
              />
            ))}
```

```js
{this.props.handleDeletePrice && (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="delete-btn"
                    onClick={() => this.props.handleDeletePrice(this.props.price)}
                    >
                      X
                    </button>
                    )}
```

Comment: Thanks, got it to work. I am a beginner in React and forgot this simple solution!